# iMacros javascript files in Chrome or IE? (Firefox strange behaviour)

Tags: firefox, imacros

Here's my problem:
There is this website that allows you to vote one time per day for a specific person. This is how the website works:
If you visit the website the first time, or 24 hours have passed since you last did, you are presented with a recaptcha image you have to 
solve to be able to vote that day. After you do vote for the day, a counter ( 23 Hours and 59 Minutes ) will appear and will prevent you 
voting twice that day.

To pass this, I bought some proxies, created new accounts
with each proxy on the website and tried to vote with each account.

This is what I did:
- I had my Account using my IP address ( Account #no_proxy)
- I created a new account using one of my proxy addresses. ( Account #proxy )

I logged in with my account ( Account #no_proxy ) on Chrome, and voted successfully, (23 h and 59 min) showed up. 
I logged in with the proxy account (Account #proxy) on Mozzila Firefox, but as soon as I did that the counter (23 h and 59 min) showed up
as if I've already voted with my proxy account

I cleared my browsing history, cache, cookies, (all data) and tried again with the same proxy account, the same counter appeared.
I switched to Chrome, cleared all browsing data there, set up the proxy there, logged in and surprise, surprise, it works now!!! I can vote
with my proxy account!
I switched to IE, cleared all browsing data there, set up the proxy... and it works here too!
I switched back to Firefox, cleared all cookies etc... And it doesn't work again! I tried to change the user agent as if it was Chrome or IE but it still did not work using firefox.
Maybe it's worth mentioning, the website uses cloudfare services.

The plan was to make an IMacros js file that votes using one account, signs out, sets the new proxy, clears the browsing data, signs in using the 
new account and repeats the cycle for each IP address. But iMacros js files are only supported in Firefox. The Imacros scripts are already developed for Firefox, so there is no way to change browsers.

Sorry for the long introduction, here is the question finally:
What could cause Firefox to behave this way? Does it save data in other ways than IE, Chrome and other browsers do? 
Is there a way to use Imacros js files in Chrome, IE?
How could I solve the Firefox issue, so that it works like Chrome and IE does?

Comment: You can try to use “Pale Moon” browser instead of “Firefox”. Sometimes I play my js-scripts (that deal with ‘PROXY ADDRESS’) in such software combination: “iMacros for Firefox 8.6.0” and “Pale Moon Version: 25.2.0” (with Shockwave Flash disabled). Probably, this approach could help you.

Comment: @Shugar thank you very much for your help. But it still shows the counter when I log in. What could be different about Firefox based browsers seeing the same computer after I've deleted my cookies, cleared all browsing data? Chrome and IE don't have this issue.

Comment: I think the issue could be somehow connected to so called “Evercookie” etc. Maybe, you’ve heard of such cookie types that can’t be erased. (By the way, ‘stackoverflow’ recognizes a user even if cookies and the browser cache are cleared!) I don’t know what difference as to storing data is between Firefox-based browsers and IE or Chrome. However, in addition can suggest to experiment with portable versions of “Firefox” or “Pale Moon”.